# Poor performance when drawing thousands of cubes

Tags: c++, directx-9, voxel

I'm a **beginner** with DirectX and working on a **Minecraft clone**/**voxel engine**. I'm trying to render a certain amount of cubes inside a RenderFrame function. What I noticed is that the performance drops quickly as soon as I render a few thousands of them (I get fps in the range between 5 and 10). What kind of optimization is required? Notice that I'm using a single vertex buffer for just one cube and then applying translations for every other cube. Is this bad practice?
Here's the code:

```
// flexible vertex format that I'm using
struct CUSTOMVERTEX {
    FLOAT X, Y, Z;
    D3DVECTOR NORMAL;
};
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL)
void render_frame(void)
{
    // ...  view transform ...

    // ... projection transform ...

    // world transform
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
    d3ddev->SetIndices(i_buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i != 4096; ++i)
    {
        // ... translation for every cube ...
        d3ddev->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 24, 0, 12);
    }
}

void setup_scene(void)
{
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },    // side 1
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, },

        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },    // side 2
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, },

        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },    // side 3
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, },

        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },    // side 4
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, },

        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },    // side 5
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },

        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },    // side 6
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, },
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(
        24 * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
        0,
        CUSTOMFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &v_buffer,
        NULL
    );

    VOID* pVoid;

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)& pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();

    // create the indices using an int array
    short indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,    // side 1
        2, 1, 3,
        4, 5, 6,    // side 2
        6, 5, 7,
        8, 9, 10,    // side 3
        10, 9, 11,
        12, 13, 14,    // side 4
        14, 13, 15,
        16, 17, 18,    // side 5
        18, 17, 19,
        20, 21, 22,    // side 6
        22, 21, 23,
    };

    // create an index buffer interface
    d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(
        36 * sizeof(short),
        0,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &i_buffer,
        NULL
    );

    // lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
    i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)& pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    i_buffer->Unlock();
}
```

Comment: use [instancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/efficiently-drawing-multiple-instances-of-geometry) to reduce your draw calls

Comment: *(I get fps in the range between 5 and 10* -- You *are* timing a release (optimized) build and not a debug build, right?  If so, please mention that in your post.

Comment: Why DirectX 9 and not DirectX 11 ?